# Is it possible to load a webview into a NSMenuItem in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem

When I try this code, I get the error: 
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WebView", referenced from:  objc-class-ref in AppController.o`

```
webview=[[WebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100,30)];
NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webview.mainFrame  loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.webViewMenuItem setView:webview];
```

webViewMenuItem is a NSMenuItem linked through an IBOutlet.

Comment: Not sure, but have you included webkit framework ?

Comment: Yes, webkit is included. I've found some people supposing it should work, but no evidence of success!

Comment: Ah, I had it included but forgot to link the framework in the app settings! The error has disappeared but it's not loading the page.. thanks for the pointer

Comment: I have no idea why there's no evidence of the webview on the NSMenuItem. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Am not near a computer now.. But can you set web load delegates and see if its getting loaded ? As google has a lot of white space and it might not fit the frame

Comment: I checked with a page I own and realtime google analytics, and the site is loading. I also tried changing the `setView` to the `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` and `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` runloops, but still no visible evidence

Comment: I dont see anything wrong in your code. But I am not sure where you are loading the web view (in `appDidFinishLauncing` or ?) . But I did the same added a menu item, hooked up an outlet and set its view to a webview and voila there was a tiny browser in my menu. If you could post the full code we can debug the issue I guess. You can go through the source code [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96486753/WebMenu.zip) I am not sure if this is what you wanted. Just out of curiosity could you let me know what you are doing with a web view in a menu ?

Comment: Fantastic! I was trying to load the webview in an app controller for the menu from a statusItemClicked action (mine's a status bar-only app).. but going from the `appDidFinshLaunching` in the app delegate now works! What I'm doing is building an app that tracks some user data and uploads it to a central server, where the data is rendered to a bespoke visual output which I want to preview in the menu. In the future I may move to a OS X widget, but I'm not sure how fast the takeup of yosemite will be. Really appreciate the help! thanks

Comment: when I say OS X widget, I mean OS X Notification Widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok for the sake of completing this question :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WebView",
>   referenced from:  objc-class-ref in AppController.o

Thats because Webkit framework was not added to project.

> Is it possible to load a webview into a NSMenuItem in OS X

Yes its possible, but make sure to load the webview once parent view is done loading completely.